# Unit Of Work Pattern - Getting repositories with a factory

Tags: c#, generics, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am following a tutorial to do with the `Repository Pattern` in a combination with the `Unit Of Work` pattern.

I essentially have:

```
interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
  //...
}
class Repository<T> where T : class
{
  //Implemented methods 
}
interface IFooRepository
{
  IQueryable<Foo> GetFoos();
}
class FooRepository : Repository<Foo>, IFooRepository
{
  IQueryable<Foo> GetFoos() {}
}
```

The above represents my `repositories`, in a basic sense. I then have a `Uow` class.

```
public class MyUow
{
  public void Commit() { }
  public IRepository<Bar> Bars { get { return GetStandardRepo<Bar>(); } }
  public IFooRepository Foos { get { return GetRepo<IFooRepository>(); } }
  private IRepository<T> GetStandardRepo()
  {
    return RepositoryProvider.GetRepoistoryForEntityType<T>();
  }
  private T GetRepo<T>()
  {
    return RepositoryProvider.GetRepository<T>();
  }
}
```

My problem is coming where the tutorial I am following only ever instansiates a `Dictionairy<Type, object>` in the `RepositoryProvider` class and doesn't seem to fill it, so the method used in `GetRepo<T>` doesn't work.

```
public virtual T GetRepository<T>(Func<DbContext, object> factory = null) where T : class
{
  //Look for T in the dictionairy by typeof(T)
  object repoObj;
  Repositories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out repoObj);
  if (repoObj != null)
    return (T)repoObj;
  //Not found or a null value, make a new instance of the repository.
  return MakeRepository<T>(factory, Context);
}
private T MakeRepository<T>(Func<DbContext, object> factory, DbContext dbContext) where T : class
{
  var f = factory ?? _repositoryFactories.GetRepositoryFactory<T>();
  if (f == null)
    //Exception here because this is null
    throw new NotImplementedException("No factory for repository type");
  var repo = (T)f(dbContext);
  Repositories[typeof(T)] = repo;
  return repo;
}
```

My question is essentially what is the correct way to implement this pattern and where I am going wrong? Should I instansiate the `Dictionairy<Type, Func<DbContext, object>` with a the list of known repositories? This seems dirty. I am driving myself insane trying to solve this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what a bout a link to the tutorial

Comment: @Tar It's on `Pluralsight` so most people wont have access to it.

Comment: I would say that if you aren't able to construct an example solution according to the tutorial, then it's a bad tutorial.
The problem itself is a bit too virtual to be easily answered...

Answer (score 0):

What I see from beginning is that your `Repository<T>` doesn't implement `IRepository<T>`, so it should be like this:

```
class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
  //Implemented methods 
}
```

Then your completely secret tutorial should describe how `_repositoryFactories.GetRepositoryFactory<T>()` can discover your `IRepository<T>` implementor `FooRepository` - maybe it willbe autodiscovery, maybe you need to register something somewhere.

Next, again I know nothing about your specific tutorial and factories etc, but I suppose you may need to use `GetRepo<Foo>` instead of `GetRepo<IFooRepository>`, because right now this `IFooRepository` looks meaningless... or maybe again you miss something in this `IFooRepository` declaration, and it should be like `interface IFooRepository : IRepository<Foo>` - and again, it greatly depends on particular discovery implementation for factories you are using.

Comment: Points: 1. My problem isn't with the repositories, they are fine. 2. The tutorial isn't "*secret*", it is on Pluralsight which is a paid service. If you have access to it, feel free to go and watch. 3. Why is the use of interface meaningless? The use of concrete types have less meaning. Interfaces allow for dependancy injection. 4. The question itself is relating to a specific set of patterns, not my code. The code is just a majorly scaled down example, take it with a pinch of salt :)

Comment: 1. .GetRepositoryFactory<T> cannot be discovered - so maybe not as good as you think

2. http://www.esreality.com/files/placeimages/2009/71946-SarcasmSign.jpg

3. I don't talk about OOP concepts - I just say that this particular interface is meaningless from the question perspective.

4. Patterns are ok. Code is not. SO we have to talk about code :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not found the answer yet,  I followed through the tutorial and was able to run it (the tutorial sample). If you're sure that you have implemented it right, take note of this,

The Repository Dictionary is by default, null and will only have value of the not standard repos (e.g. IFooRepository) when it is first requested. Therefore, if you're checking the value in debug of the Repository Dictionary and an IFooRepository is not yet requested it is for sure that you will not see it there. Have a code to access the IFooRepository first then it will make a repository for that in the MakeRepository method of the provider class.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper class called `RepositoryFactories.cs`
You need to add an entry for your custom Repository to the dictionary

```
{typeof(IFooRepository ), dbContext => new FooRepository (dbContext)}
```